# Distributing Scapy in a Python Virtual Environment

Tags: pip, virtualenv, scapy, python-3.9

I need to distribute a package among a group of servers that are, by design, all running the same OS and version of Python. I have a CI script in Gitlab that is pretty straight forward. I'm using a custom Alma 8.8 image with Python 3.9.18 installed.

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 -m venv envname 
source somename/bin/activate
# i've done python3/pip3 --version to verify the version
pip3 install -r requirements.txt # <- scapy is in here
# do some cleanup
# zip up everything including the 'envname' folder
```

Everything gets built and packaged just fine. However when I copy the package to another machine, unzip and run it I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'`.

The OS and Python versions in the image in which I'm building this .zip file match those of the machine where I'm trying to run it.

When I create the virtual environment on the server and run that version it works fine. Running `pip install` on the server where the script will be running is **not** an option.

Any suggestions on what I could be overlooking? Thank you.